# Load images based on dynamic path in ReactJs

Tags: json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to display images in a shopping cart i'm making but its not showing up. Do i have to import each image? I know my paths are fine because it worked before.I think there might be something wrong in my product.js file but I can't figure it out.

Here is my Product.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class Product extends Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        const { id, addToCart, removeFromCart, isInCart } = this.props;

        if (isInCart) {
            removeFromCart(id);
        } else {
            addToCart(id);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { name, price, currency, image, url, isInCart } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="product thumbnail">
                <img src={image} alt="product" />
                <div className="caption">
                    <h3>
                        <a href={url}>{name}</a>
                    </h3>
                    <div className="product__price">{price} {currency}</div>
                    <div className="product__button-wrap">
                        <button
                            className={isInCart ? 'btn btn-danger' : 'btn btn-primary'}
                            onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            {isInCart ? 'Remove' : 'Add to cart'}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Product.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    price: PropTypes.number,
    currency: PropTypes.string,
    image: PropTypes.string,
    url: PropTypes.string,
    isInCart: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    addToCart: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    removeFromCart: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default Product;
```

The data comes from this product.js

```
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Reggae Blaster',
        price: 10,
        currency: 'GOLD',
        image: '../assets/blaster_1.png'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Juicy Blaster',
        price: 10,
        currency: 'GOLD',
        image: 'images/02.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Full Body Reggae Armor',
        price: 20,
        currency: 'GOLD',
        image: 'images/04.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Reggae Spikes Left',
        price: 5,
        currency: 'GOLD',
        image: 'images/06.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Reggae Spikes Right',
        price: 5,
        currency: 'GOLD',
        image: 'images/05.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Black Full Body Reggae Armor',
        price: 20,
        currency: 'GOLD',
        image: 'images/03.jpg'
    }
];

export default data;
```

I am pulling all the data except the images just don't show up

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Assuming that you are using webpack, you need to import the image in order to display it like

```
<img src={require('images/06.jpg')} alt="product" />
```

Now that your image data is dynamic, 
directly specifying the import path like

```
<img src={require(image)} alt="product" />
```

doesn't work.

However you can import the image by making use of template literals like

```
<img src={require(`${image}`)} alt="product" />
```

So your code will look like

```
render() {
    const { name, price, currency, image, url, isInCart } = this.props;

    return (
        <div className="product thumbnail">
            <img src={require(`${image}`)} alt="product" />
            <div className="caption">
                <h3>
                    <a href={url}>{name}</a>
                </h3>
                <div className="product__price">{price} {currency}</div>
                <div className="product__button-wrap">
                    <button
                        className={isInCart ? 'btn btn-danger' : 'btn btn-primary'}
                        onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        {isInCart ? 'Remove' : 'Add to cart'}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

P.S. Also make sure that your image path is relative to the file you are importing them in.

Comment: Hi Shubham Khatri, This approach solved my problem but I get next warning adding images dynamically: WARNING in ./index.html
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <!DOCTYPE html>
| <html lang="en">

Comment: @JuanReinaPascual, I guess you might have already solved this problem by now, but just to share, you need to configure your `webpack` config to load `jpeg, svg` file types

Comment: Great stuff... This doesn't work: ```img src={require(filePath)}```. This does works ```img src={require(`${filePath}`)}```

Comment: After searching for almost 2hrs, found this perfect answer. Using backtick is the key here - require(`${image}`)

Comment: @Shubham Khatri how do you deal with this if you are using a build tool like webpack in where the images are put to public directory directly? I get a browser error saying that the corresponding image is not found in that directory which is relative to the server..?

Answer (score 2):

`img src={require(`${filePath}`)}`
-- working
you also need to add default to get exact URL

```
img src={require(`${filePath}.default`)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I adding this comment so that future guys can benefit.

So the problem I faced was I had an array of people, and I needed to display the profile picture of each person

Solution

2 files :

- data.js which contains an exported JSON object
- main.js which has my react component

#### Step#1 : data.js

in data.js import all your local image asset files that you need.
ex.

```
import ProfilePicN from "./ProfilePicN.jpg";

export default [
  {
    "name": "PersonN",
    "image": ProfilePicN 
  }
]
```

*important: no quotes around the import, quotes on everything else as they are all literals

#### Step#2:

```
      import data from "./data.
    
      .
      .
      .
    /*inside the react component*/
     {
       data.map((dataItem,key)=> {
          <img src={dataItem.image}>
       })
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put those images in folder where your bundled application lives.

Comment: how do you deal with this if you are using a build tool like webpack in where the images are put to public directory directly?