# Render numbered for loop in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to show a series of pictures but the following code does not replace `{i}`with the actual number. It renders:

```
<div>
  <img src='/img/picture{i}.jpg' />
  <img src='/img/picture{i}.jpg' />
</div>
```

This is the code.

```
class Pictures extends Component {
  render () {

    return (
      <div>
        {Array.from({length: 2}, (_, i) => (
          <img src='/img/picture{i}.jpg' />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reactjs - Images not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334874/reactjs-images-not-displaying)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work (with ES6 template literals syntax):

```
<img key={i} src={`/img/picture${i}.jpg`} />
```

Alternatively, you can use String concatenation syntax:

```
<img key={i} src={'/img/picture' + i + '.jpg'} />
```

Comment: and don't forget `key` : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Note, tho: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: @Andy: I know that, but in the practical sense, I never had an issue with an index being used as a key (of course, my experience may depend on app-specific things like component tree hierarchy, dependencies, etc.). Not sure about others' experiences.