# How to pass image url as prop in React

Tags: reactjs, frontend, jsx

I have an image uri that i want to pass as prop so that i can load it when it when the component is rendered. as i will be changing images i cannot have a static uri. but i keep getting this error

```
Error: Cannot find module "."
```

although it does work when i statically load the images. Also i need to use the img element and not Image.

```
require('./cube.jpg')
```

here is my code

here is my parent class declaring the component:

```
<InputSection ref="inputS" ImD={this.getData} imageUri={this.state.imageurl} />
```

imageurl state is defined as:

```
imageurl: './cube.jpg',
```

child component:

```
return(
<div style={style}>

<br/>

<img  ref="image" src={require(this.props.imageUri)} onLoad={this._onImageChanged.bind(this)} />
<canvas style={{display:'none'}}width={300} height={300} ref="inputCanvas" >

</canvas>
</div>
);
```

Comment: Also, avoid using string literals in refs.

Comment: I know it's a little late, but I had the same issue and this answer solved it for me. Hope this helps some one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45334965/6115855

Answer (score 4):

Did you try the other way around? I am assuming you will import the images in your parent component. Also the reason you are getting that error is probably because your Parent component and Child component are not in the same directory. The image path is `./cube` relative to Parent which means it resides in the same directory as Parent.

**Parent Component**

```
<InputSection ref="inputS" ImD={this.getData} imageUri={require(this.state.imageurl)} />
```

**Child Component**

```
<img  ref="image" src={this.props.imageUri} />
```

Comment: The components are in the same directory i tried to directly load image without using require as you suggested but it throws no error and also nothing appears. i also tried to use the absolute path with no luck.

Comment: in order for require to work the component must know the source of the image before the component loads or is initializing right? or is it when the application is build/compile time?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
<img src={require(${this.props.YourPropName})} alt="My Image"/>
```

and take any name as a prop in the tag and then pass it!!