# Relative path of images not working in react application?

Tags: image, reactjs

I have created a js file where an array contains multiple objects. Every object has an image path given. Using for loop, I am importing every object to my component. Everything works fine except the image. It's broken. It's not taking the relative path. I have stored all the images in a folder. Below is my code:

Data.js

```
export const dashboardUtil = [
     {
       title: "Posts",
       count: 500,
       image: "/src/images/1.png"
     }
   //rest of the objects
]
```

Component.js

```
let blocks = [];

for(let i=0;i<dashboardUtil.length;i++){
    blocks.push(
            <Col xs={12} md={6} sm={6}>
              <div className="main-block" className="stats-block">
                <h3>{dashboardUtil[i].title}</h3>
                <p>{dashboardUtil[i].count}</p>
                <img src={dashboardUtil[i].image} />
              </div>
            </Col>
          );
}
```

Comment: is there any console error like 404?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [load-images-based-on-dynamic-path-in-reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334874/load-images-based-on-dynamic-path-in-reactjs/45334965#45334965)

Comment: Adding to the duplicate, you image paths are not relative but absolute, to be relative, they should start like `./`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
image: "/src/images/1.png"
```

This is not a relative path, its absolute (starts with slash).  If you intend it to be relative, use `./` e.g. `./src/images/1.png`.

The bigger issue is that you're providing a path to a local resource to the context of the users browser.  It expects this to be a `http(s)://` resource.  You need to provide an endpoint that your web server handles and serves up the resource.

Either:

- Your image needs to go into a location your web server can access, and you need to set the `img` `src` attribute to reference that location
- You should look into [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) and a file loader plugin that takes a local image path via `require()`, and copies that to an accessible location.

Answer (score -1):

use :
import **image** from "../pathToImageFolder/image1.png";

//path to **image** will be automatically constructed by webpack

`<img src={image}>`