# how to fetch image from the API using react js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

i can't display the image in my website, which is fetched from the API.

this is my image fetching/showing code.

```
this.state.filteredData.map((data,i) =>
                    <div>
                        <span>{data.details.name}</span>
                        <br/ >
                       <img source={{uri:data.details.image}} style={aStyle} />
                        <br/>
                        <span>{data.details[ 'section of law' ]}</span>
                        <br />3

                        <span>{data.details[ 'type of person' ]}</span>
                    </div>

const aStyle={
    width:300,
    height:360
};
```

[image]

only image box is showing.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Load images based on dynamic path in ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334874/load-images-based-on-dynamic-path-in-reactjs/45334965#45334965)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load images based on dynamic path in ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334874/load-images-based-on-dynamic-path-in-reactjs)

Comment: doesn't work...

Comment: Can you try this : '<img src={{data.details.image}} style={aStyle} />' ?
Also, can you give us an exemple of your data object ?

Comment: Can you open dev tools, inspect the element and see if there are any errors?

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src={{uri:data.details.image}} style={aStyle} />
```

Answer (score 0):

image has src attribute and you can pass image url string or base64 image data to it.

```
<img src={data.details.image} style={aStyle} />
```