# JS: How to dynamically grab variable names

Tags: javascript, import, create-react-app

I'm using the create-react-app template.

In one of my components, I am importing the path to several images like so.

```
import iconAvatar from '../img/icon-avatar.png';
import iconHome from '../img/icon-home.png';
import iconVendor from '../img/icon-vendor.png';
```

Now let's say I have a variable like this, which determines what image to use.

```
let imageType = "avatar"; // or "home", or "vendor", etc.
```

I want to dynamically render out the proper image based on the value of imageType (without having to use a convoluted if-else structure)

Something like the following (except that it won't work)

```
<img src={"icon"}{imageType}/>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: All you need to do is concatenate, but you might consider using an object containing all images, rather than three independent variables

Comment: What exactly is the output HTML supposed to look like? There is no `type` attribute on the `img` tag that I am aware of or the MDN lists as being available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your file names follow that standard you can just use string concatenation.

```
<img src={'../img/icon-' + imageType + '.png'} />
```

or even cleaner with [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)..

```
<img src={`../img/icon-{$imageType}.png`} />
```

**Edit:**
When using webpack you must use `require` and when using `require` string concatenation does not work, however string interpolation still works. So..

```
<img src={require(`/img/icon-{$imageType}.png`)} />
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45334965/5817001) for more information.

Comment: This worked: <img src={require(`/img/icon-{$imageType}.png`)} />
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options available:

First using an object as suggested by @CertainPerformance

```
const images = {
  avatar: require('../img/icon-avatar.png'),
  home: require('../img/icon-home.png'),
  vendor: require('../img/icon-vendor.png')
}

<img src={images[imageType]} />
```

Or you can use a switch / if statement

```
switch (imageType) {
  case 'home': return <img src={iconHome} />;
  case 'avatar': return <img src={iconAvatar} />;
  case 'vendor': return <img src={iconVendor} />;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm going with @fqhv's solution with template literals as it's a bit cleaner.