# Passing an image dynamically as props to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, webpack

In my parent component, I'm receiving an object from an API that I later inject an image into as a key/pair value. I then pass that object off to a child component to be rendered, and I have attempted to follow this post to do so:

[Load images based on dynamic path in ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334874/load-images-based-on-dynamic-path-in-reactjs)

However, despite copying webpack's necessary image import format, I'm still receiving this error.

```
Error: Cannot find module '../images/test.jpg'
```

That path can be used directly in the component just fine... but when imported as such... things break.

Here is the code from the child component:

```
const WorldInfo = (props) =>  {
    return props.world ? (
        <div className={props.className}>
            <h1>{props.world.map}</h1>
             <img src={require(`${props.world.image}`)}/>
        </div>
    ) : 
        null
}
```

Thanks for looking friends!

Comment: Using them without the require should work?

Comment: `that I later inject an image into as a key/pair value` is a strange thing to say about JavaScript. Can you provide an example of how you do this.

Comment: Instead of passing a full path (relative or absolute), pass only the last name (test.jpg). WebPack will detect a dynamic require and will bundle all the files inside the folder, like so: `require('../images/' + props.world.image)`. I'm not sure if this is your problem, but that's how WebPack works.

Comment: @isherwood but maybe the image is not served as an HTTP request. It only forms part inside the project as an asset, like you do with `.json` for example. For this you need an image loader actually, which will convert the image to a base64 data URL.

Comment: @Reactgular When I say inject, all I mean is this, ```map.data[1].result.image = "../images/testPlanet.jpg"```

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzalez had the answer! Now my injection looks like this, ```map.data[0].result.image = "testPlanet.jpg"``` and my reference in the child component looks like this ```<img src={require('../images/' + props.world.image)}/>```

Comment: Woah nice. If you don't mind, I'll create an answer for this :P

Comment: Please do! Thanks! You're the man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing a full path (relative or absolute), pass only the last name (`test.jpg`). WebPack will detect a dynamic require and will bundle all the files inside the folder, like so: `require('../images/' + props.world.image)`.